# Read mpq_t from a binary file

Tags: c, fread, gmp

I have written mpq_t to a binary file called "data", and now I am trying to read mpq_t from the file one by one, but I kept having segfault at the line: gmp_printf("%Qd\n", buf). I've been debugging for a while but couldn't figure out where went wrong.

```
int main(){

    FILE *fp = fopen("data", "rb");
    if (fp == NULL){
            perror("FILE open failed");
            exit(1);
    }

    mpq_t buf;
    mpq_init(buf);

    while (fread(&buf, sizeof(mpq_t), 1, fp) == 1){
            gmp_printf("%Qd\n", buf);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that I have a memory issue with buf after reading from the file. I have also tried mallocing instead of initiating, but it did not work either.

```
    mpq_t *buf = (mpq_t *)malloc(sizeof(mpq_t));

    if (buf == NULL){
            perror("malloc failed");
            exit(1);
    }

    while (fread(buf, sizeof(mpq_t), 1, fp) == 1){
            gmp_printf("%Qd\n", *buf);
    }
```

Comment: See documentation for [I/O of mpq_t](https://gmplib.org/manual/I_002fO-of-Rationals.html#I_002fO-of-Rationals) or [GMP formatted output](https://gmplib.org/manual/Formatted-Output.html#Formatted-Output)+[GMP formatted input](https://gmplib.org/manual/Formatted-Input.html#Formatted-Input), depending on your need and/or preference. Any `mpq_t` values should be written to the stream using one of the output functions in the documentation, and the corresponding read function should be used to read the value in the same manner. In other words, you shouldn't simply `fwrite` and `fread` the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use gmp_fprintf and gmp_fscanf to write and read:

```
   gmp_fprintf (FILE *fp, const char *fmt, ...)
   gmp_fscanf (FILE *fp, const char *fmt, ...)
```